# My LateX doesn't work anymore

Tags: errors

My LateX did work the whole time without problems. Now I just started my project and it didn't work anymore and i don't know what is wrong. I use TeXmaker and I installed TeXLive and MikteX.

The error message, which is displayed is :

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.1.18) 2 FEB 2016 09:09
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./Thesis.tex
(./Thesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9n> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.18 \hypersetup
{
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.19 c
olorlinks=false,
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
```

This continues with multiple error about missing fonts and letters.

I don't know what happened.

Hope you can help me.

Greets, 
Patrick.

Comment: Welcome, are you using that template from Sunil Patel (also known as graduateTemplate and easythesis on sharelatex)? Did you mess with the class file? the template is unfortunately not well designed, better get another template.

Comment: You won't get far without learning some basics about LaTeX. You don't need to install MiKTeX _and_ texlive. The package hyperref is somewhat special. According to the error message, you probably forgot to load it. Please, read a beginners guide to LaTeX. You will save lots of time by following this advice. Good luck!

Comment: you have used `\hypersetup` without defining it by `\usepackage{hyperref}` (that would never have worked)

Comment: Have you , by accident, deleted the very first line of your tex-file?

Comment: It can be helpful to provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).